# Subtracting "1" from all div ID's if greater than X?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to change the ID of all divs if they are greater than a certain number.

Basically I am allowing users to delete a Div if they want. All div's are ID'd in order from zero to however many divs are in the column.  If a user has 8 divs the ID's will look like:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

If a user deletes the third div, every div with an ID greater than 2 should subtract by 1 so it remains in order.

I previously had it set up so that the app would count the number of deleted div's and take that into account for other code that relies on the div's being in order, however a new feature has made that way too hacky to work reliably.

I have tried something like this, but it's returning `NaN` for all the div ID's.

```
if ($(".queueListDiv .track").attr("id") > deletedId){
  $(".queueListDiv .track").attr("id", ($(".queueListDiv .track").attr("id") - 1))
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if you are referring to # as the ID identifier or number.  But the ID's must be numbers.

Comment: `$(".queueListDiv .track").attr("id")` I think needs to be parsed. Also, consider looking into `caching`. Calling selectors multiple times could lead to performance issues.

Comment: Using _id_ like this looks like an anti-pattern. Consider using some other attribute, such as making a choice based on the n-th of a _class_

Comment: Is your `id` property based on the element's index of its parent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NaN` means, not a number. You need to parse the right ID before you can do it right. Check this out:

```
// loop through the tracks
$(".queueListDiv .track").each(function () {
  // current element
  var $this = $(this);
  // get the id in number form
  var id = parseInt(this.id, 10);
  // if it is greater, do
  if (id > deletedId) {
    // remove one and set it back
    $this.attr("id", id - 1);
  }
});
```

I advice you from refraining from setting the `ID` value to be a pure numerical value.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work?

```
$(".queueListDiv .track").each(function () {
  var $el = $(this);
  var id = parseInt($el.attr("id"), 10);
  if (id > deletedId) {
    $el.attr("id", id - 1);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `attr(attribute, function)` which will loop over all the elements. In your code you aren't checking specific instances

```
$(".queueListDiv .track").attr("id", function(idx, oldId){
    return +oldId > deletedId ? +oldId - 1 :  oldId;
});
```

Comment: Nice one. For the 'beauty' of the thing, a version using [ECMAScript 6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): `$(".queueListDiv .track").attr("id", (i, o) => +o > deletedId ? +o - 1 : +o);`

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` means "not a number", what in your case is exactly the case. You are subtracting a number from a string. Convert the id number into a number with `parseInt(string, 10)`. The 10 represents the decimal system and should be added to avoid strange behavior of the function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping a jQuery resultset of your elements like.

```
var $collection = $();
```

Then each time you create one you can do...

```
$collection.add($newJqueyObject);
```

So in this way you don't have to look them up.  Now part two.  When you create them you could do

```
$newJqueryObject.data('numericId', value);
```

Where value is an integer, not a string.  Then later when you want to find the ones to change you could do a simple filter.

```
$collection.filter(function(){ return $(this).data('numericId') > somevalue; });
```

I may have missed some stuff, but you get the idea.  You'd also need to remove from this collection when they were deleted so they don't hang around.

Answer (score 0):

More short solution:

```js
$(".queueListDiv .track").each(function (index, elemenet) {
  var id = parseInt(elemenet.id, 10);
  if (id > deletedId) {
    elemenet.id = id - 1;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which doesn't involve *condition*.

```
$(".queueListDiv .track").attr("id", function(i, o) {
  return o - +(o > deletedId);
});
```

This code returns the
`oldId - 0 if oldId > deletedID is false`
`oldId - 1 if oldId > deletedID is true`

A version using [ECMAScript 6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) that I don't recommend to use due to poor browser compatibility. Just showing it for the cool syntax.

`$(".queueListDiv .track").attr("id", (i, o) => o - +(o > deletedId));`